# angular-cli import own classes like angular classes

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

**I'm quite sure this question has been asked before, I just don't know where to search for it, so please refer to other questions if this is a duplicate**

In my angular-cli application I can import classes that are in the node_modules directory by there name under the node_modules directory, e.g. the angular router can be imported with

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
```

If I add my own classes under node_modules I also can import them without specifying the relative path to that class. So my questio is:

Can I add an angular-cli/webpack configuration  so that my imports are mapped to my source directory and I can import my own classes like this

```
import { MyCustomService } from '@app/services/my-custom.service'
```

which maps `@app` to `src/app/` directory

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's already configured to allow for this. Beside just using relative paths, you can also use absolute paths starting from the `src`. So currently, you can do `'app/services/my-custom.service'`. If you want to be able to do `'@app/services/my-custom.service'`, then I think just changing the `app` folder name to `@app` should work. Just hope that nothing else in the CLI configuration is dependent on that specific name for that folder.

Comment: thanks for the help, I tried to accomplish this with webpack, but it already is supported by typescript (baseurl in tsconfig.json)